# JAXB duplicate object

Tags: java, jaxb

How to avoid creating different object instances when they are suppose to be the same ?

Here is the xml file :

```
<family>
    <person>
        <firstName>John</firstName>
        <father>
            <firstName>Gary</firstName>
        </father>
        <mother>
            <firstName>Jane</firstName>
        </mother>
    </person>
    <person>
        <firstName>Philip</firstName>
        <father>
            <firstName>Franck</firstName>
        </father>
        <mother>
            <firstName>Jane</firstName>
        </mother>
    </person>
</family>
```

father and mother elements are of type `Person`.
I have two persons with the same mother, when I unmarsharll the xml file it creates two different instances of Person class.  Is there a way to tell that they should be the same object ?

Comment: An XML file can represent the equivalent of "pointers". But if your data is as you have shown it, you'll have to post-process the object tree and collapse duplicate/multiple identical objects. Do you also create the XML file? Can you influence its structure?

Comment: Yes it is me who create the xml file.  That structure was convenient, I'll try to see if I can find another way to structure it then.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An XML file can use the equivalent of "pointers". In terms of XML Schema,

```
<xsd:element name="name" type="xsd:ID"/> <!-- in Person-->

<xsd:element name="persref" type="xsd:IDREF"/> <!-- the "pointer" to a person -->
```

The "pointers" are values of the Person field, which must be unique (so a person's name alone is generally not sufficient). Instead of marshalling the entire object only a "pointer" value is marshalled. The full objects themselves must be marshalled separately.

In your case it is simple as every Person occurs once and only once as a family member. You simply use "persref" elements for father and mother. - See [this tutorial](https://jaxb.java.net/tutorial/section_4_3_1-Assembling-Data-with-Links-ID-IDREF.html#Assembling%20Data%20with%20Links%20%28ID,%20IDREF%29) (also [a second section](https://jaxb.java.net/tutorial/section_6_2_11-Annotations-for-Object-References-XmlID-XmlIDREF.html#Annotations%20for%20Object%20References:%20XmlID,%20XmlIDREF)) for the technical details.